# How to turn off the graphics adapter on a Lenovo G570?

Tags: kubuntu, hybrid-graphics

I have Ubuntu running on my Lenovo G570, how can I turn off my Radeon graphics card, which is getting heated up a lot while I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu Community Help Wiki provides an interesting [about](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) Hybrid Graphics and how to disable/enable graphical cards.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have an option to turn it off at all. It depends on your computer's BIOS. Go into BIOS (press F2 during Boot), then look for an option to select the graphic adapter. If there is such an option, you can choose between 'Switchable' and 'Integrated'. Select the 'Integrated' Option.

I'm highlighting again that your BIOS may or may not have this setting available. If it doesn't, then there's not much you can do about it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.
I turned off my graphics card using the command

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch.

Now its not heating up and i am getting a battery life of about 3.5 hours where i had been getting about 1.5 hours for full discharge before. Its cool.

Thanks OrangeTux for the Link.